# Original Work for Pareto Refinement of NE under Strategic Form

Tags: reference-request, game-theory

Just looking to see if anyone has any knowledge of original work for pareto refinement of NE under strategic form. I want to give credit to the refinement in a paper I am writing. I pulled the refinement from Nachbar's notes on "Topics in Advanced Game Theory", but obviously that is not a reliable source to cite.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're referring to the criterion of **payoff dominance** in equilibrium selection. This idea can be attributed to Harsanyi and Selten (1988):

- John C. Harsanyi and Reinhard Selten. 1988. *A General Theory of Equilibrium Selection in Games*, MIT Press.

Comment: Yes, yes this is it! I think Pareto refining is a slightly less scholarly definition of it, but yea this seems to be it. Much appreciated.